# How to set wp_query on search page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

We have search page, that is using standart global $wp_query and takes parameters like s and category_name from $_GET.

I want to add some parameters in wp_query on search page. But more complicated than parameters passed in $_GET.

That's why I tried to create new WP_Query like

```
$args = array(
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'hour'      => 9,
        'compare'   => '>=',
    ),
    array(
        'hour'      => 17,
        'compare'   => '<=',
    ),
    array(
        'dayofweek' => array( 2, 6 ),
        'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
    ),
),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$new_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And take results in

```
<?php while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>
```

But it doesn't work. Even if to reset global $wp_query with

```
wp_reset_query()
```

I can rewrite global $wp_query going inside and compare date of every post with my date and to unset post if doesn't match. But I am shure it is not right way to do what I want.

What am I dooing wrong?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/advanced-wordpress-search-with-wp_query/)

Comment: @RohitKishore thank you so much. 
The right way is to use pre_get_posts filter and set any query_var throw set function.
In my case, for example, I wrote $query->set('date_query', array(
            '0' => array(
                'after' => $after,
                'before' => $before,
                'inclusive' => true
            )
        ));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function search_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if(is_search()){
        if(empty($_GET['before'])){$before = '01.01.2050';}else{$before = $_GET['before'];}
        if(empty($_GET['after'])){$after = '01.01.2000';}else{$after = $_GET['after'];}

        $query->set('date_query', array(
            '0' => array(
                'after' => $after,
                'before' => $before,
                'inclusive' => true
            )
        ));
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```